# Setting post hook on Facebook page

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

It's possible to set with Facebook Graph API new post hook on page, that isn't mine?
For example I want to get a request with post content on my site (I use Node.js - maybe in some packet is that option) when new post appears - can I do it and how to?

I did research, but I found nothing useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's possible to set with Facebook Graph API new post hook on page, that isn't mine?

No, that is not possible.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks:

> *“Subscriptions for the object type page will only be valid for Pages that have installed the app.”*

Installing the app on the page means you need to have admin access to the page.

Comment: I see you are expert in Facebook, maybe there is other option e.g. getting few last post on page by AJAX? If there isn't I will cry

Comment: Just getting public page posts does not require webhooks, but simply requesting the data from the `/page-id/feed` endpoint. But since all API requests require an access token, you either need to make users log in to your app first (if you want to do this client-side), or you have to make the API request server-side (so that you can use the app access token, which must never be exposed in client-side code.)

Comment: Okay, but I still don't understand at all. Can I do server-side request to `/page-id/feed` with Facebook developer's app, but when I don't have admin access to that page (or admin's access token)?

Comment: If the page is public and not access-restricted in any way, and the posts are not targeted to specific audiences - then yes, you can get them using your app token. In any other case, you need to use a user token for a user that can see the content, or a page access token.